# Execute stdout in current shell

Tags: bash, shell, variables, parent-child

When using metaflac the stdout is in the following format:

```
$ metaflac --show-tag ARTIST myfile.flac
ARTIST=myartist
```

Is it possible to execute stdout (`ARTIST=myartist`) in the current shell, so that the variable `ARTIST` contains `myartist`? If I do `metaflac ... | bash`, it's all in a child shell, so it can't access the variables from the parent shell.

/edit: If the field is multi-word, so that the output is like this:

```
ARTIST=Alter Bridge
```

after `eval $(metaflac --show-tag ARTIST myfile.flac) the variable`ARTIST`is set to`Alter`. Is it possible to make bash act just as if was

```
ARTIST="Alter Bridge"
```

i.e. don't use the space as a variable input delimiter?

Comment: What is `ARTIST`? Something you're setting or something that's returned by metaflac? Is it actually a variable?

Comment: ARTIST is the name of the field. The second line is just stdout.

Answer (score 2):

Run it like this: `eval $(metaflac --show-tag ARTIST myfile.flac)`

Answer (score 2):

```
eval `metaflac --show-tag ARTIST myfile.flac`
```

Comment: @marmistrz i forgot eval

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to eval: [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) -- it wraps a command so that it's output acts like a file.

```
source <(metaflac --show-tag ARTIST myfile.flac)
```

Responding to the edit: assuming you know all the output is variable declarations:

```
while IFS='=' read -r var val; do
    declare "$var=$val"
done < <(metaflac --show-tag ARTIST myfile.flac)
```

Yes, two `<` symbols: the first is the redirection, the second begins the process substitution syntax.

Comment: If you would like more whitespace, you can put any number of newlines inside the `(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Another option: use `cut`. It's not exactly executing, but it's a workaround

```
ARTIST=`metaflac --show-tag ARTIST myfile.flac | cut -d'=' -f 2-`
```

Works like charm!